# Amazon Advertising API: ASINs report request returns " Filter type is null"

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

I try to get a ASINs report from the Amazon Advertising API.
I created a POST request to https://advertising-api-test.amazon.com/v2/asins/report

**Request - Headers:**

I am sure the headers are correct (including Authentication) because other similar report requests work correctly.

```
Content-Type: application/json
Amazon-Advertising-API-ClientID: XXXXXXXXX
Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope: XXXXXXXXX
Authorization: Bearer Atza|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**Request - Body:**

```
{
    "campaignType": "sponsoredProducts",
    "reportDate":"20190528",
    "metrics": "campaignName,campaignId,adGroupName,adGroupId,keywordText,keywordId,matchType,asin,otherAsin,sku,currency,attributedUnitsOrdered30dOtherSKU,attributedSales30dOtherSKU"
}
```

**Expected Response:**

```
{
    "reportId": "amzn1.clicksAPI.v1.m1.5D133A56.9efaeb90-46d1-41e8-82bb-fc9acf2798b8",
    "recordType": "ASIN",
    "status": "IN_PROGRESS",
    "statusDetails": "Generating report"
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "code": "400",
    "details": " Filter type is null",
    "requestId": "TVHWE5DY8PJNNBEQRK46"
}
```

**Question:**

I have no idea what filter type is required for the request or how else i have to interpret this error. I can not find any information in the official documentation https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/v2/reference/reports#ASINs-report
So i hope to find an solution here...

Comment: @sparkle
1. this is not related to my question
2. your link is not working

Answer (score 1):

I think your URl:https://advertising-api-test.amazon.com/v2/asins/report
is not correct .
try it once hope it will works
https://advertising-api-test.amazon.com/v2/sp/asins/report

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30902163)